# How come in IE I can't center my video?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Why in IE does it not center my video? http://101river.com/record in all other browsers it appears to be fine.

```
<div style="width: 320px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">

<object id="container" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="340" height="540" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="align" value="middle" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="FlashVars" value="contentId=4c5b364b86f31" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="src" value="http://videos2.videobloom.com/container.swf" /><param name="name" value="container" /><param name="flashvars" value="contentId=4c5b364b86f31" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><embed id="container" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="340" height="540" src="http://videos2.videobloom.com/container.swf" name="container" wmode="opaque" quality="high" flashvars="contentId=4c5b364b86f31" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" align="middle"></embed></object>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click <a href="http://101river.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/calendar_48.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-210" title="calendar_48" src="http://101river.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/calendar_48.png" alt="" width="48" height="48" /></a> to schedule your Twounce.

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have comments before your doctype which trigger quirks mode. Remove the comments and it should make IE render your page in standards mode ( obeying more CSS rules ) and do it properly ( that way you don't have to resort to the text-align hack ).

Comment: `<!--
Theme Name: Kelontong
Theme URI: http://www.icreativelabs.com/
Description: None.
Version: 
Author: iCreative Labs
Author URI: http://www.icreativelabs.com
Tags: blue, black
 Kelontong 
 http://www.icreativelabs.com/
 This theme was designed and built by None,
 whose blog you will find at http://www.icreativelabs.com/
 The CSS, XHTML and design is released under GPL:
 http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php
--> `

Comment: This is in wordpress... not really sure how to take out doc type? does this page not need a doc type?